# debug dart hang in launching on vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Reproduce:

- run `dart create projectname`
- open projectname on vscode and hit F5 to start debug

[image: launching]

Then vscode is launching debugger forever.

If stop debugger, it prompt timeout.
[image: timeout]

---

If just run `dart run`, it will print `hello world!` as expected.

`bin/projectname.dart` genereated by `dart create`:

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  print('Hello world!');
}
```

Dart is installed within flutter. And flutter app cannot debug similarly, maybe related to this issue.

Dart and flutter extensions on vscode are installed. Nothing changed after re-installing them.

Some answers mention `launch.json`, but I never configure it and configuration should be default.

Result of `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1566], locale zh-CN)
    • Flutter version 2.10.2 at D:\Program Files\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 097d3313d8 (12 days ago), 2022-02-18 19:33:08 -0600
    • Engine revision a83ed0e5e3
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\ProgramData\Android\Sdk
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio 生成工具 2019 16.11.10)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
    • Visual Studio 生成工具 2019 version 16.11.32126.315
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.20348.0

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.36.0

[!] Proxy Configuration
    • HTTP_PROXY is set
    ! NO_PROXY is not set

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1566]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 98.0.4758.102
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 98.0.1108.62

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Update:

- Nothing changed after re-install flutter/dart to directory without space.
- Nothing changed after re-install vscode.
- Nodejs file can be debugged as expected
- I try to capture log https://gist.github.com/sym233/7671732365c483a71ff9042885e61466, it seems to hang in spawning vm server at 3:00:03